# How to use a "Do While" loop to iterate through a list

Tags: java, loops, do-while

```
public static boolean hasGreaterDoWhile(List<Integer> numbers, int number) {
    int d = 0;
    do {
        if (numbers.get(d) > number){
            return true;
        }
        d++;
    }
    while (d < numbers.size());
    return false;
}
```

(JAVA only)
P.s This is a function i have tried, in order to check the first argument, and if it contains a number that is larger than the second argument, it will then return true, and flase otherwise.
Note that it is using do while loop. I just don't know which part of this code i have done wrong, because the system keeps telling me that "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0".
Thank u, any hint will be much appriciated.

Comment: Think of do-while this way: it will be executed at least once. There are rarely any use-cases for it. While is often better, but you can also use "for each" loops to get rid of indices entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your list of Integers is empty. you can't access an index of an empty list:

```
public static boolean hasGreaterDoWhile(List<Integer> numbers, int number) {
    int d = 0;
    if (numbers.isEmpty()) return false;
    do {
        if (numbers.get(d) > number){
            return true;
        }
        d++;
    }
    while (d < numbers.size());
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanx, i see now.

Answer (score 2):

A `do-while` control block works as follows:

1. Execute the `do` block
2. Check the condition. If it holds, return to (1)

Notice the order of this flow. Unlike a standard `while`, `do-while` will always execute one iteration before checking the condition. Therefore, for an empty list you will always try to access the 0-index element of the table, which does not exist, hence the error. You can use a `while` loop to avoid this:

```java
public static boolean hasGreaterDoWhile(List<Integer> numbers, int number) {
    int d = 0;
    while (d < numbers.size()) {
        if (numbers.get(d) > number){
            return true;
        }
        d++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether the collection is empty

like this

```
    if(numbers == null || numbers.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    int d = 0;
    do {
        if (numbers.get(d) > number){
            return true;
        }
        d++;
    }
    while (d < numbers.size());
    return false;
```

Comment: thank u. I see, so unlike while loop, when u are using do while loop, just to always check if the list is empty before hand.